DiagrammeR: Error in render_graph(., as_svg = TRUE) : object 'display' not found
When trying to set as_svg = TRUE in DiagrammeR::render_graph() I get an error Error in render_graph(., as_svg = TRUE) : object 'display' not found. as_svg help in render_graph() does not state any specific conditions that need to be met.
How can I make as_svg = TRUE work?
library(dplyr) # 1.0.10
library(DiagrammeR) # 1.0.9

# works
create_graph() %>%
  add_balanced_tree(k = 2, h = 3) %>%
  render_graph()

# errors with "Error in render_graph(., as_svg = TRUE) : object 'display' not found"
create_graph() %>%
  add_balanced_tree(k = 2, h = 3) %>%
  render_graph(as_svg = TRUE)


You may try updating DiagrammRsvg FWIW.

I'm already using the currently most recent version (0.1).
